# How to return a number when using a char function

Tags: c++, function

I have a school homework and we have to resolve a number of problems using predefined function headers. There are a couple of problems that require to return the number x and not the character 'x' when the function header looks something like this :

```
"unsigned char sumBinaryFigure(unsigned long long number)"
```

I resolve the problem inside the function and when it comes to the return part, I don't know how to make it return the number x and not the character 'x' because the function is declared unsigned char. I've tried return int(result) but it doesn't work.

Comment: It does return an (unsigned, as you can see) number. Only it prints as a char.

Comment: Most probably the result is *displayed* as a character. By the output facility you're using. Try just putting a `+` in front of it to promote the type up to `int`. This works on every C++ implementation where `sizeof(int)>1`. Which is most every platform except some TI digital signal processors.

Comment: An `unsigned char` (or a `char`) happens to be an integer. It is merely a display convention to print characters. If you want to print an `unsigned char` as an integer result, use something like `out << int(uc)`.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys, I think I got understood what's up.